# SharePoint 2013 Document Library Default View for Site Collection

Tags: 2013, document, view, library, template

We have added new columns to doc. library on PWA Sharepoint 2013.

we want to save this view as default doc.library template for every site created on PWA site collection, is it possible?

Every site created in PWA should have this view...